# Confusion with E/Z configuration

Tags: stereochemistry

Could someone please illustrate how to determine the *E/Z* configuration of this molecule?

[image: image below]
[image]

What I understand so far is that if the two highest priority substituent on each side are on the same side, then it's *Z* and vice versa.

Now, how can I handle such a structure? 
I've considered it and I thought it might be $\ce{CH-CH3}$ on one side (up), and $\ce{CH2CH2}$ on the other. However, I don't think it's right.

Bottom line is that I don't understand how to fractionate the ring into two substituents.

Comment: This molecule has not isomers about the double bond. Simple as this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The CH3 and C2H5 groups are both smaller than the rest of the cycle. So these two groups can be forgotten and this molecule is Z.

Comment: While the configuration is "Z", the IUPAC 2013 Blue Book recommends no designation.: "P-91.2.2 Omission of stereodescriptors
The  omission  of stereodescriptors specifying  double  bonds  is  recommended  in the case  of  three-  through  seven-membered  unsaturated  alicyclic  compounds  where  any double bond has a fixed configuration, 'Z'  in the case of hydrocarbons...."

Comment: Thank you. So, just to understand this properly, we consider the cycle as a shared branch for the two pi-bond carbons? (each of them is considered to bear the same ring).

In other terms, I want to know if I could break down this structure to something like this   (a,b)>C=C<(e,d) 
if (a) is the methyl branch (CH3) and e is the C2H5, would it be correct to say b and d are the same?

Comment: I have added to your post your structure numbered. At C1, C6 ranks higher than the CH2 of the ethyl group because it is attached to C5 (CHH) while the ethyl group terminates with CH3 (HHH). AT C2, C3 (CCH) ranks higher than the methyl group (HHH). Therefore, the ring is unofficially, as I commented above, of the Z-configuration. Read up on Cahn-Ingold-Prelog (CIP) rules.

Comment: Thank you for both the clarification, I do have a better understanding now, and the recommendation on the CIP rules; that's exactly what I need.